# Case insensitive sed for pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I want to show block in file from `string` until it gets to new empty line.
For that I wrote: `sed -n '/Flashback/,/^$/p' /tmp/flashback.log`. no issues here.

Now I want the string to be case-insensitive so I added `I` before the `p`  but `flashback` string doesn't return anything as it should.

Comment: If you want `Flashback` to be case insensitive, put it there `/Flashback/I,/^...`.

Comment: See [this sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.10) for solutions in sed not supporting case insensitive flags.